# parsing a PDB file in C++ To collect the variable names

Tags: c++, parsing, pdb-files

Can anyone suggest a way to parse PDB files in C++? I need to get access to Variable names and specifically the returned variables names.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

The actual format of PDB files is undocumented outside Microsoft.

Fortunately, there's an excellent supported DLL for reading information out of them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679267(v=vs.85).aspx